# Сортировка словаря полученного из json файла по значению

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, сортировка, словари

Нужно реализовать сортировку словарей в Json файле по году рождения

```css
[
  {
    "Имя": "Arthur",
    "Фамилия": "Pendragon",
    "Год рождения": 1138
  },
  {
    "Имя": "Leo",
    "Фамилия": "Tolstoy",
    "Год рождения": 1828
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = [
    {
        'Год рождения': 1138,
        'Имя': 'Arthur',
        'Фамилия': 'Pendragon'
    },
    {
        'Год рождения': 1828,
        'Имя': 'Leo',
        'Фамилия': 'Tolstoy'
    }
]

users = sorted(data, key=lambda user: user['Год рождения'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import itemgetter
data = [
    {
        'Год рождения': 1138,
        'Имя': 'Arthur',
        'Фамилия': 'Pendragon'
    },
    {
        'Год рождения': 1828,
        'Имя': 'Leo',
        'Фамилия': 'Tolstoy'
    }
]
users = sorted(data, key=itemgetter('Год рождения'))
```

[How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python)